# Get a particular value of a variable from the function which is inside a class

Tags: php

I want access only a particular value from the function declared inside the class

```
class Animal
{
    var $name;

    function __Construct($names){
        $this->name=$names;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal 
{
    function prop($ht, $wt, $ja)
    {
        $height=$ht;
        $weight=$wt;
        $jaw=$ja;
    }
}

$dog= new dog('Pug');
$dog->prop(70, 50, 60);
```

I want to echo only a particular value from the `dog` function `prop`.

something like `dog->prop->jaw;`

How is this done?

Comment: Typically, the `__construct` method name is all lowercase

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like this...

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    private $props = array();

    public function prop($height, $width, $jaw) {
        $this->props = array(
            'height' => $height,
            'width'  => $width,
            'jaw'    => $jaw
        );
        return $this; // for a fluent interface
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->props)) {
            return $this->props[$name];
        }
        return null; // or throw an exception, whatever
    }
}
```

Then you can execute

```
echo $dog->prop(70, 50, 60)->jaw;
```

or separately

```
$dog->prop(70, 50, 60);
echo $dog->jaw;
```

Comment: ||but it shows me error

||"private $props = [];"

||Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: You must be using an old version of PHP. You need to use the old array declaration syntax. I'll fix it up in my answer.

Comment: oh thats fine phil thanks for your immediate replies

Comment: it works for me fine in old array declaration thanks this what i expected